# How to get line number from SearchMatch object?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

in my plug in after performing search, each matches are sent to acceptsearchmatch(searchmatch) function as objects of searchmatch.I want to get the line numbers where the match happened.cant use getoffset because it gives relative to source buffer.how can i get the line number?help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is: a `SearchMatch` give you a `SearchRange`, meaning several lines can potentially be included in that Range.

The solution is to parse the **[Document](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/text/IDocument.java.htm)** associated to the object returned by the SearchMatch in order to compute those line numbers.
The relevant method is  [`getLineOfOffset(int offset)`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/text/IDocument.java.htm#ixzz0eIZlyf9T)

You have [here an example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DLTK_IDE_Guide:Step_3._Towards_an_IDE), in the case where the object is a `IMember`

```
ISourceRange range = member.getSourceRange();
if (range == null){
  return null;
}

IBuffer buf = null;

ISourceModule compilationUnit = member.getSourceModule();
if (!compilationUnit.isConsistent()) {
  return null;
}

buf = compilationUnit.getBuffer();
final int start = range.getOffset();
String contents = buf.getContents();
Document doc = new Document(contents);
try {
  int line = doc.getLineOfOffset(start);
  ...
```

Comment: @Nishan: `ISourceModule` comes with the Eclipse Dynamic Languages Toolkit (DLTK). You need to get the document associated with the element found by the `SearchMatch` another way.

Comment: @Nishan : See slide 16 of http://www.eclipsecon.org/2005/presentations/EclipseCON2005_Tutorial29.pdf for a possible way.

Comment: And potentially http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/propertiesfileeditor/PropertyKeyHyperlink.java.shtml

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private int getLineNumber(SearchMatch match) throws BadLocationException,
        IOException, CoreException {

    IResource resource = match.getResource();
    if (!(resource instanceof IFile)) {
        // Log Error
        return -1;
    }
    IFile file = (IFile) resource;
    int offset = match.getOffset();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[offset];
    int read = file.getContents().read(bytes, 0, offset);
    if (read != offset) {
        // Log error
        return -1;
    }
    String contents = new String(bytes);
    Document fileSource = new Document(contents);
    return fileSource.getLineOfOffset(offset) + 1;
}
```